# Compare set of dates in Excel

Tags: excel, date

I have this formula (which isn't working):

=IF(OR(7/9, 7/10, 7/13, 7/14) = OR(6/29, 6/30, 7/1, 7/2), "N", "Y")

The above dates are just an example. The dates will vary on my actual spreadsheet for each row, as each of the date is a derived value based on a formula.

What I want to do is to see whether there is an overlap between the dates on the LHS and the dates on the RHS, and display 'N' if there is, and 'Y' if there isn't.

So, if 7/9 or 7/10 or 7/13 or 7/14 is equal to 6/29 or 6/30 or 7/1 or 7/2, then print 'N', else print 'Y'.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) around a [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) to achieve an array processed count.

[image: SUMPRODUCT over COUNTIF]

The formula in E3 is,

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2:A5, C2:C5)), "N", "Y")
```

Your original sample data did not produce any matches as I understood the criteria so I forced 2 matches on a second set of sample data in A7:A10, C7:C10 for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped. This works for a range, but each of my dates are derived with formulas.  

This is my actual formula (which doesn't work for the final Y/N result, but works for deriving the dates):  

`=IF(OR(A3-2, A3-1, B3+1, B3+2) = OR( WORKDAY(EOMONTH(A3,-1),-1), WORKDAY(EOMONTH(A3,-1), 0), WORKDAY(EOMONTH(A3,-1), 1), WORKDAY(EOMONTH(A3,-1), 2) ), "N", "Y")`

A3-2, A3-1, B3+1 & B3+2 on the LHS gives dates, and so does all the WORKDAY(EOMONTH(...)..) functions on the RHS.

How would I incorporate the SUMPRODUCT/COUNTIF logic in this?